# How to @Ignore Sqlite entity column(s) with Android Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

My current Android application has a requirement to fetch rows from my local Sqlite database with a count field.

I realise I need to have my DO Entity have this count field defined and @Ignore(ed)

I google searched and found this [page](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data)

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    val firstName: String?,
    val lastName: String?,
    @Ignore val picture: Bitmap?
)
```

However, when I copy and paste this exact Kotlin code into my application it fails to build with these exceptions

```
database_room:kaptStagingDebugKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/rossulbricht/projects/silkroad/database_room/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/stagingDebug/org/dread/pirate/database_room/model/User.java:7: error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
public final class User {
             ^
  Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
  User(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,android.graphics.Bitmap) -> [param:id -> matched field:id, param:firstName -> matched field:firstName, param:lastName -> matched field:lastName, param:picture -> matched field:unmatched]
e: /Users/rossulbricht/projects/silkroad/database_room/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/stagingDebug/org/dread/pirate/database_room/model/User.java:9: error: Cannot find setter for field.
    private final int id = 0;
                      ^
e: /Users/rossulbricht/projects/silkroad/database_room/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/stagingDebug/org/dread/pirate/database_room/model/User.java:11: error: Cannot find setter for field.
    private final java.lang.String firstName = null;
                                   ^
e: /Users/rossulbricht/projects/silkroad/database_room/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/stagingDebug/org/dread/pirate/database_room/model/User.java:13: error: Cannot find setter for field.
    private final java.lang.String lastName = null;
                                   ^
w: [kapt] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).

> Task :networking:mergeStagingDebugNativeLibs
> Task :android_idplus:generateStagingDebugRFile
> Task :networking:processStagingDebugManifest

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

My questions are...

How do you ignore columns in a Kotlin data class room entity?

Why don't google android examples work?

I am using

```
Android Studio 3.5
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 9, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.6


buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://sdk.smartlook.com/android/release"
        }
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    minSdkVersion = 21
    supportLibVersion = '1.1.0-beta01'

    coreKtx = '1.2.0-alpha04'
    materialMaterial = '1.1.0-alpha10'
    legacySupportV4 = "1.0.0"
    recyclerView = '1.1.0-beta04'
    lifecycleExtensions = '2.2.0-alpha04'
    playServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    archLifecycleVersion = '2.2.0-alpha04'
    roomVersion = '2.2.0-rc01'
    archPagingVersion = '2.1.0'
    archWorkerRuntimeVersion = '2.3.0-alpha01'
    constraintLayoutVersion = '2.0.0-beta2'
    browserVersion = '1.0.0'

    appCompatVersion = '1.1.0'

    junitVersion = "4.12"
    testRunnerVersion = '1.1.0-alpha4'
    espressoTestCoreVersion = '3.1.0-alpha4'
    uiautomatorVersion = '2.2.0-alpha4'

    leakcanaryVersion = "1.6.1"
    commonsTextVersion = '1.7'

    rxbinding2Version = "2.2.0"
    picassoVersion = "2.71828"
    retrofit2Version = '2.6.1'
    rxAndroidVersion = '2.1.1'
    rxJavaVersion = '2.2.11'
    jacksonKotlinVersion = '2.10.0.pr1'
    okhttp3Version = '4.1.1'
    okioVersion = '2.4.0'
    jakewRxrelay2Version = '2.1.0'

    daggerVersion = '2.24'

    numbusJoseJwtVersion = '7.1'
    interComVersion = "5.4.1"

    guavaAndroidVersion = "28.1-android"
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here

```
@Entity
data class User(
@PrimaryKey val id: Int,
val firstName: String?,
val lastName: String?,
@Ignore val picture: Bitmap?
)
```

Modify it so that

```
@Entity
data class User(
@PrimaryKey val id: Int,
val firstName: String?,
val lastName: String?,
@Ignore val picture: Bitmap?
){
constructor():this(id=null,firstName=null,lastName=null,picture=null) }
```

Then another error will come as , there're no setters, so replace `val` with `var`

```
@Entity
data class User(
@PrimaryKey var id: Int,
var firstName: String?,
var lastName: String?,
@Ignore val picture: Bitmap?
){
constructor():this(id=null,firstName=null,lastName=null,picture=null) }
```

Here's the gradle which I'm using for room

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
```

add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in top

```
ext.room_version = '2.2.0-rc01'
```

Answer (score 2):

The values of that entity should be `var data: String?` with a constructor:

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    var firstName: String?,
    var lastName: String?,
    @Ignore var picture: Bitmap?
){
  constructor: this(firstName = "", lastName = "")
}
```

Of course you can do `val`s , but you should add constructor.

Or just `val`s:

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    var firstName: String,
    var lastName: String,
    @Ignore var picture: Bitmap
)
```

So really, `@Ignore` has nothing to do with that. For more, [refer this article](https://coroutinedispatcher.com/posts/solving-room-cannot-find-setter-for/).

You can't really have `val`s and nulls at the same time. Room doesn't allow that. If you want your variables to be nullable stick to `var` and add constructor to the data class as described above.

> Why dont google android examples work?
> If you check your data class and the code from the page you refer to, you will notice this difference.

Answer (score 0):

This can also work

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int = 0,
    val firstName: String? =null,
    val lastName: String?=null,
){
    @Ignore var picture: Bitmap? = null
}
```

```
val u = User().apply{picture=Bitmap.build()}
```